# WordPress dosn't save page/post updates

Tags: pages, save-post

Any suggestion what could cause the problem, that a WordPress site doesn't save any changes in one specific page?

After making any changes in a page, it doesn't save the changes. However, from time to time, can save some tiny letters changes, but not larger content with an added new sentence.

Some notes:

- For the page are working Autosave, but can't use autosaved version.
- All caches are cleaned more than once in a browser and related caching plugins.
- Tested as well with all deactivated plugins and default themes.
- The website is pretty large with a huge database.
- Can't see any errors in the console or something.
- For the page are around 17 revisions, but can't rever any of them as well.

Comment: If you have Access to the MySQL Database with a Tool Like phpmyadmin, Check the row within the wp_posts table with the Pages id. Maybe the changed Page ist saved, but then reverts in reloading or Something? Also, you can Install the Plugin query Monitor to See If There are errors Happening when you save the page

Comment: Thanks, @kuchenundkakao In the database, I can see only these all 17 revisions and not saved new changes. Do you know on which section I need to make attention in the Query Monitor plugin?